# Custom action not firing using link_to with remote=true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Very new to ruby on rails and trying to get my first ajax call working. It is making the ajax call, but it always calls the #index action and seems to ignore the URL parameter. Here's the code:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
def flag
    logger.debug "in flag user"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :layout=>false }
    end
  end
end
```

In my routes.db:

```
resources :users do
    member do
      post 'flag'
      get 'flag'
    end
  end
```

And then in my view I create the link like this:

```
<%= link_to "Flag User", :url => flag_user_path(user.id), :method => :get, :remote => true %>
```

the HTML source is:

```
<a href="/users?method=get&amp;url=%2Fusers%2F1%2Fflag" data-remote="true">Flag User</a>
```

rake routes produces this:

```
flag_user  POST   /users/:id/flag(.:format)   users#flag
           GET    /users/:id/flag(.:format)   users#flag
```

Whenever I click on the link, the user#index method always gets executed. How do I get the user#flag method to execute?

Comment: Can you include the html that it creates for that link?

Comment: i update the question with the html and rake routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the :url symbol. I changed:

```
<%= link_to "Flag User", :url => flag_user_path(user.id), :method => :get, :remote => true %>
```

to:

```
<%= link_to "Flag User", flag_user_path(user.id), :method => :get, :remote => true %>
```

and everything works was expected. I was incorrectly using it like link_to_remote which requires the :url symbol. Thanks everyone for their input.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in how you are defining your routes. It needs to be like this,

```
resources :users do
  post 'flag'
  get 'flag', on: :member
end
```

Check the rails guides for routing to get more idea.

Comment: It is within "member do" so should be the same as individual on: => :member. I have tried both ways with the same result (your code actually doesn't work until you remove "member do".

Answer (score 0):

If you run rake routes, I think you'll see that the route created with name "flag_user_path" expects "post" not "get"

Comment: I tried changing the "method" parameter for the link_to helper to :post but get the same results. <%= link_to "Flag User", :url => flag_user_path(user.id), :method => :get, :remote => true %>. If I look at the server logs, I still see it requesting a GET though.

Comment: The code you've just included in that comment also has method of "get".

Comment: If you use `button_to` instead of `link_to` it will automatically be post instead of get...

Comment: @taryn east was a typo when i pasted. I tried :method => :post to no avail and also tried the button_to. I figured out the issue was actually not to specify a key for the url. This works: <%= link_to "Flag User", flag_user_path(user.id), :method => :get, :remote => true %>